# Water Leak in Flip Fluid add-on

Tags: modeling, add-on

I am trying to create a water simulation on a hexagonal platform. I am using the add-on Flip Fluid v1.1.0 Demo. I assign functions to all objects of the scene. Obstacle, Fluid, Domain. After baking, water flows through the obstacle. I assigned the physics Rigid Body to the obstacle. The result is similar.
Is there anything I can do to keep the water on top of the obstacle? Or is this not possible for this add-on? I have a similar result when using MantaFlow. Blender version 2.92, 2.93.

[image]

Comment: normally just increasing the resolution will help. If you want an exact help, please provide blend file so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I have tried 300 and 600 resolution. Nothing helps.

Comment: Where can I attach a file?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and read the instructions

Comment: OK. I have uploaded this file. It is called "Ocean Testing 04.blend".

Comment: read the instructions. You have to copy that generated link back to your question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gzGYD0o2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gzGYD0o2/)

Comment: Thank you for your blend file. Unfortunately the objects now have the name "domain" and "water" but they have no physics property at all so we cannot check what you might have done wrong.

Comment: Here is my physics file. It's called "Ocean Testing 05.blend". [Ocean Testing 05.blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zWbEewln/)

Comment: I watch drawing lessons on YouTube. But there all the waves are drawn in cubes or parallelograms. And the water takes the form of a Domain. But the Domain cannot be made hexagonal. Maybe it is impossible to do this for my case?

Comment: I don't know whether the domain can be hexagonal, but since you don't "see" the domain at all, why bother that it is a cube? You can do all "visible" hexagonal - the water/inflow/geometry and the obstacles. So there is no real "need" to make the domain hexagonal. The domain is just the "volume" where the simulation takes place - that's all.

Comment: That's what I do. I just do not understand why water flows through the walls of the obstacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that is causing leakage is that the obstacle object contains non-manifold geometry:

[image]

For objects to work correctly in the simulator, the geometry must be manifold/closed/watertight ([Documentation](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Manifold-Meshes)).

The next issue that you will run into is that liquid will leak through thin walls at low resolutions. You can increase resolution to fix this, but this may increase simulation bake time significantly depending on how thin the obstacle is ([Documentation and Solutions](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Scene-Troubleshooting#thin-obstacles-leaking-fluid)).

An alternative solution to increasing resolution could be to remodel the simulation setup to prevent any leakage at low resolutions:

1. Create a simple 6 sided cylinder. This will be the container for the liquid.
2. Set this object to an obstacle and enable the [Inverse option](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Obstacle-Inverse-Workflow). This will enable the obstacle to contain liquid inside of it and no liquid will be able to escape the object.
3. Create a cube and model a sloped ramp to match the original hexagon container. Set this object to an obstacle.

[image]

Here is a revised .blend file including these changes: [image]

Your original objects can still be used for rendering while these new objects can be used just for the simulation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Great explanation. I will continue painting.